# Conditional prop 'lazy ' in b-tab with 'v-for'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, tabs, lazy-loading, bootstrap-vue

I am using BootstrapVue's `b-tabs` with the `lazy` prop as [documented](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs#lazy-loading-tab-content). I have the following problem:
I need to load SOME of the tabs lazy, and others NOT while using `v-for`.

```
<template>
    <b-tabs>
        <b-tab lazy v-for="element in elements" :key="element.id" :title="element.title">
            <div>[lots of stuff here]</div>
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</template>
```

I do not want to do split up the v-for like this:

```
<template>
    <b-tabs>
        <b-tab v-for="element in elementsNonLazy" :key="element.id" :title="element.title">
            <new-component />
        </b-tab>

        <b-tab lazy v-for="element in elementsLazy" :key="element.id" :title="element.title">
            <new-component />
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</template>
```

As `lazy="false"` / `lazy="true"` is unfortunately not a working option: is there another way which does not require to split up the `v-for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lazy` is a prop not a directive that accepts a boolean value that could be bound a condition based on the current element like :

```
 <b-tab v-for="element in elements" :lazy="element.isLazy"  >
```

or something like :

```
<b-tab v-for="element in elements" :lazy="element.id>5"  >
```

when you want to use a boolean value to a prop you should bind it using `:` like `:lazy="false"`